# SQL query to format the result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, formatting

I have data in following format:

```
24  Asian Fish
24  Atlantis
24  Bakery
24  Bistro
24  Bon Appetite
24  Camo
24  Fish Bones
25  Black
38  Black
38  Burgundy
38  Dark Green
38  Navy
38  Red
```

Could you please suggest what query can be used to format it in following way:

```
24       Asian Fish|Atlantis|Bakery|Bistro|Bon Appetite|Camo|Fish Bones
25       Black
38       Black|Burgundy|Dark Green|Navy|Red
```

This is for SQL Server 2005.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: SQL databases **store** data - you shouldn't use them to do data visualization / presentation - that's the job of a UI component

Comment: You need `group_concat` or similar. This will certainly be a dupe. Your other questions are SQL Server so probably of this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005

Comment: how did you decide what to group on? I'm assuming there is some kind of category id somewhere.  If you're using MySQL, check out `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Comment: @marc_s: There are millions of reasons why one could want to do this in the DB. I guess that's beyond this question...

Answer (score 5):

Since you didn't specify what database system you're using - here's one way to do it in SQL Server (2005 and up):

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT ID,
    STUFF((SELECT '|' + t2.Fishy
     FROM dbo.YourTable t2
     WHERE t2.ID = t.ID
     FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') 'Fishes'
FROM dbo.YourTable t
```

This will produce the output:

```
ID  Fishes
24  Asian Fish|Atlantis|Bakery|Bistro|Bon Appetite|Camo|Fish Bones
25  Black
38  Black|Burgundy|Dark Green|Navy|Red
```

Comment: Sorry it is in SQL Server 2005

Comment: @Om: should work in SQL Server 2005, too ! **2005** (and newer)